# Angular2 this scope issue in the component

Tags: angular, typescript

I've problem with typescript in angular2.
I have simple class just with one property used for save reference to the method.

```
export class Icon{ 
  public OnClick?:() => void;
}
```

Then in the component I set method into this variable

```
iconSource: Icon[] {
     { OnClick: this.myOnClickMethod() }
}

public myOnClickMethod(){
     this.toggleFilterRow();
}

public toggleFilterRow()
{
    //some logic for filtering the grid
}
```

In the html template I am calling *icon.OnClick()* which is correctly calling **myOnClickMethod()**
Everything is working perfect, until is executed method **myOnClickMethod()** in which **this** isn't scope of the component but it's scope of the Icon. (result = unknown method *toggleFilterRow()* )
Could you please send me some hints this "scope" problem? Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you try to do it in this way?

Comment: I have a set of icons in icon list variable. Every icon needs to have onClickAction. This list I am using in the component then. Do you know better solution?

Comment: You can work with parent and child templates. Put the icon on the parent template and open child template with `<div *ngIf="childOne"><childOne></childOne></div>`
This way your you only have to set the icon ones and render the rest in the content of your screen. See it as a header(parents)-content(childs)-foorter(parent)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iconSource: Icon[] {
     { OnClick: () => { this.myOnClickMethod(); } }
}

public myOnClickMethod(){
     this.toggleFilterRow();
}

public toggleFilterRow()
{
    //some logic for filtering the grid
}
```

When using the fat arrow(=>) the context of this is preserved.

Comment: Thank you so much for help :) I knew about fat arrow but I didn't know that's possible to use like this :)